# Device class is marked obsolete in .net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui

Recently I updated to the latest version of .net MAUI and I was a bit surprised to see that the MAUI Device class has now been marked as Obsolete

I have multiple use cases where I am using the device class for something or the other.

For instance now the mainthread method is obsolete:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{});
```

Is there a new helper class that is going to be performing these activities now or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, doesn't this functionality exist in the `MainThread` class? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread

Comment: That's obviously just an example, here the whole class seems to be marked obsolete. @DavidL

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5088

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Maui now has a namespace with a bunch of Device related classes you can find them under Microsoft.Maui.Devices

[image]

**OG answer:**

As Jason pointed out in the comments apparently they have decided to dissolve the whole Device class and now all functionality present there is either being moved out or being replaced with other options, none under the same tree though more information [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5088)

> Device

> This is the containing class, and everything it had is now obsolete. Ready for removal in .NET 7!
> GetNamedSize, NamedSize and IFontNamedSizeService
> This used to be the only way to get scaled font sizes, but now it is built into Font. If we want to actually expose those values to the user, we can maybe use a "stringly-typed enum" to allow for supporting the other values on the system. We only had Title1, but there is also a Title2 and Title3.
> Device.Styles and ISystemResourcesProvider ("Device Styles" eg: {DynamicResource TitleStyle})
> This is the way to get the OS font styles. This may be more popular than I think, but I am just pre-emptively removing it for now.
> In both cases (named sizes and device styles), I may be missing the real uses here, so this PR is to show what is going and can start a conversation.

> If anything, some things need to be tweaked and not exist only in the Device class.

> Named Sizes
> NOTE: these values appear to be magical and do things, but at XAML parse time, they are translated into a double with no idea that they were special values. Thus, they never did respond to OS changes. Once set, they are just a number and nothing special

For named sizes, we could have Font be smarter and actually have the stringly-typed value as a field. For example:

```
class Font {
    double Size;
    string NamedSize;
    string Family;
}
```

> Then the font manager can do a check like this:

```
double realSize;
if (font.NamedSize != null) {
    realSize = GetSizeFromName(font.NamedSize);
} else {
    realSize = font.Size * scalingFactor;
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone out :)

Comment: Even Maui use Device with #pragma in his FontSizeConverter https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/FontSizeConverter.cs

Comment: Well, that's because it's not removed just deprecated they are planning to remove the concept of GetNamedSize altogether if I am not wrong. If you check the Git link in my answer. They are now expecting people to use numbers.

Comment: Yeah this link is better, with all the discusion thread already implemented
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3938

I think they will still provide an enum for this. it's just not yet done.

Answer (score 7):

So we have the [Xamarin.essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/essentials/main-thread) alternative

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{});
```

And Xamarin.essentials has been ported to [.Net Maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread) so same stuff

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{});
```

And about FontSize even Maui [FontSizeConverter](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/FontSizeConverter.cs) use Device

```
Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)));
```

So use pragma like them ;)

Update will be on this [github Discussion on the implementation of NamedSize fonts in Core](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3938)

Comment: Umm isn't it `MainThread` the class that holds this method and not platform?

Comment: Yeah you totaly right!